# Time complexity “polynomial in n”

Tags: algorithms, terminology, computational-complexity

When we say an algorithm performs in time complexity polynomial in $n$ where $n$ is a parameter of the algorithm do we mean literally $O(n)$ or $O(p(n))$ where $p$ is a polynomial?

Comment: The latter is "polynomial in $n$", the former is "linear in $n$" which is in only a subcase of the first one. You may also see "quadratic in $n$" and so on.

Comment: See this [complete answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/13626) on cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

To say that the complexity is polynomial in $n$" means that there exists *some* polynomial $p$ such that the running time is $O(p(n))$.